# R tensorflow: reading in a data frame

Tags: r, tensorflow

I have a 13000 row by 21 column data frame in R.

The first column in my Y variable and the other 20 are my X's.

I am trying to read these in as x and y tensorflow variables for processing in tensorflow.

I am using the tensorflow library for R. I am wondering if there is anyway for me to do this?

I tried using

```
x=tf$Variable(input_df[,2:ncol(input_df)])
```

But that resulted in an error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords):

> TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string,

All my columns are floating point numbers.

Thanks!